# What is a good way to setup an angular service method so that a client component can properly respond to HTTP errors that occur in the call?

Tags: angular, dependencies, angular-services

Lets imagine for example that we have an angular 8 client component defined (componentA) which depends on a method (getPeople) defined in a service (serviceA).

serviceA.getPeople in turn calls an http endpoint (rest API). Its possible that a http response from the external API returns an error (say 500)

How could we design serviceA and componentA such that componentA can respond in any way it sees fit? (rather than, say, have the serviceA determine how to respond to errors for ALL clients/callers)

Here is 1 way I believe this can be achieved. 
In **serviceA** have the method defined as

```
getPeople(): Observable<IPeople[]> {
    return this.http.get<IPeople[]>(url)
}
```

And within the **componentA**, have the caller setup as

```
this.serviceA.getPeople().subscribe(
    (response) => {
        // Do something with response
    },
    (errorResponse) => {
        // Handle error in way component wants to handle it
        // ex. Show toast message saying "Error in obtaining people. Please 
        // refresh to try and obtain people again." Something like that
    }
);
```

Are there any reasonable drawbacks to this approach?
Also, what other ways can the code be organized so that the caller (componentA) have the complete control over how it responds to errors, while at the same time designing the serviceA well for other callers?

Is the approach I describe above the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Use angular interceptors. It will act as a common medium to handle request and response for all your components. Code will also look clean. Please refer this article on how to implement. https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Comment: @RanjithS, Can you summarize how exactly interceptors are going to help with the problem mentioned above? From my understanding, interceptors are used well when trying to intercept requests being sent to backend, and say, attach a header to the request. Also, I'm not looking to setup a systemic approach to handling all errors. Specifically, I am looking to handle errors that are specific to the request/method. Ive added a comment in the error handling within the component for better clarity on this point.